# How to specify constructor within three template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, arguments

I have to define the priority_queue class in the main.

```
int main(){
...
pri_queue_t<string, vector_t<string>, cmp> q3;
...
}
```

Therefore, I tried to make a header file like below.

```
template<typename T, class V, class O>  //the last argument is alphabet 'O'
class pri_queue_t{
public:
    pri_queue_t();  //constructor
    ....
}

template<typename T, class V, class O>
pri_queue_t<T, V, O>::pri_queue_t(){}  //body of constructor**
```

The error code is

```
/home/mys/Desktop/stl_project/2_adp/main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/mys/Desktop/stl_project/2_adp/main.cc:147:43: error: ‘cmp’ was 
not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘bcmp’?
147 |     pri_queue_t<string, vector_t<string>, cmp> q3;
  |                                           ^~~
  |                                           bcmp
/home/mys/Desktop/stl_project/2_adp/main.cc:147:46: error: template 
argument 3 is invalid
147 |     pri_queue_t<string, vector_t<string>, cmp> q3;
```

I meant the cmp as option that makes pri-queue ascending. How to make the right constructor? And How to define the cmp?

Comment: How `O` is used inside `pri_queue_t`?

Comment: Do you mean to have some template parameter (maybe `O`?) that indicates wether `std::less` or `std::greater` is used as comparator? (Thus controlling wether the queue is sorted descending or ascending) Somethin like this?

Comment: what is `cmp` ? Please provide a [mre]. The error is not in the code you posted. Declaration and definition look ok, but the error complains about `cmp`

Comment: I ignored the "And How to define the cmp?" part in my answer, because I suppose you do not need it, if you do you need to explain how you want to compare the strings

Answer (score 3):

[Priority queue is](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>,
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
```

Note the default for the thrid parameter. If you do not know what else to put there then the default is probably fine:

```
template<typename T, class V>  
class pri_queue_t{
public:
    pri_queue_t();  //constructor
    ....
}

template<typename T, class V>
pri_queue_t<T, V>::pri_queue_t(){}  //body of constructor**
```

I am a bit confused by `//the last argument is alphabet 'O'`, because the third parameter for `priority_queue` is a comparator, not an "alphabet". Anyhow, then in `main`:

```
int main(){
    pri_queue_t<string, vector_t<string>> q3;    
}
```

If `vector_t` is  `std::vector`, you could also get rid of the second parameter.

Alternatively you can use the defaults from the priority_queue:

```
#include <queue>

template <typename T>
struct prio_queue_defaults {
    using container_type = typename std::priority_queue<T>::container_type;
    using value_compare = typename std::priority_queue<T>::value_compare;
};

template <typename T, 
          typename container = typename prio_queue_defaults<T>::container_type,
          typename compare = typename prio_queue_defaults<T>::value_compare>
struct my_prio_queue {
    std::priority_queue<T,container,compare> x;
};

int main() {
    my_prio_queue<int> y;
    my_prio_queue<int,std::vector<int>> z;
}
```

Note that there is no need to write a constructor for this simple example, because the compiler generated one already does the right thing.

(The trait `prio_queue_defaults` is not really needed here and it also does not help to write less code, I just used it to have meaningful names.)

Comment: Thanks for careful answer! I am not sure I understand it 100%. Anyway, I would read it carefully and it will help me so much!

Comment: @ShinMin-Young if something is not clear you just need to ask